# Upgrading LAMP on CentOS 6.2 Errors

Tags: centos6, lamp, upgrade

I have been trying to upgrade an old CentOS 6.2 server (x64) to support updates for a Drupal/CiviCRM website I have inherited.

I tried to follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9362289) but keep ending up getting the following errors ([after solving this error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27667111))

```
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
```

I have tried this multiple times with similar results and other routes as well that included upgrading to 6.9. I took a snapshot prior to doing this, so if reverting back and starting over would help, I can do that.

Does anybody know what those errors mean and how to resolve them? I have investigated the requires packages before and they all appeared to be present on the system.

Complete yum command and output:

```
[root@ ~]# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install mysql mysql-server
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.59-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.5()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libncurses.so.5()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.5()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libncurses.so.5()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.i686 0:4.013-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.5()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libncurses.so.5()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package mysql-libs.i686 0:5.1.73-8.el6_8 will be installed
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.59-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypt.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libz.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libtinfo.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librt.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libz.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librt.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libz.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libm.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypt.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libdl.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libm.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libm.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libaio.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libdl.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libdl.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libncurses.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librt.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.59-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: I would suggest you run `yum distro-sync` to hopefully get your system up to date, and then try your installation again.

Comment: It seems to do the same thing during the yum distro-sync except for php related packages now: Error: Package: php-cli-5.6.35-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)

Comment: Have you disabled some repos from which you installed packages? You should keep them enabled.

Comment: I have not disabled any repos, I only enabled remi, remi-php55, remi-php56.  I did inherit this system, so I guess there is a chance the previous owner did that, but I'm not sure why he would.

Comment: Are you sure these repos are persistently enabled in their various `.repo` files? I would go look and be certain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76122/discussion-between-tardy-and-michael-hampton).